# How to call a function on jQuery Ajax timeout

Tags: jquery, timeout

I am making an ajax call to a php file on my server.

That php file retrieves some info from various websites, so an ajax call can take 30 seconds to complete in the worst case.

All I want to do is to set a timeout value for the ajax call and to trigger a function when timeout is reached.

I think jQuery .complete is what I am looking for since it is called in any case but how to detect if it is called on timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use `.error` for that instead of `.complete`.

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

`textStatus` will be "timeout".

Answer (score 0):

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

complete(jqXHR, textStatus)

A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").